# getstream activityfeed is really slow?

Tags: getstream-io

for example, when user A fetch activity feed list

data are not include isLike Field ( key )

Because in our app, there is a like button for each feed post, and if the user has already liked it, it is activated, otherwise it is deactivated. That's why a field like isLike is needed at the same time to load the articles.

I don't know if I've seen it wrong, but in the getstream document, the api is called to see if the user has liked each post. In other words, if there are 10 posts, you have to call api number 10 to know whether or not you like it.

Calling the api repeatedly for each article is very inefficient and slow enough to be difficult to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this description/expection is wrong.

Like can be a reaction on an activity. When you can the feed, you can call enrich endpoint with own reactions and further limit kind to `like` which will return a reaction for each activity in the feed.

Exact call depends on the SDK but more or less:

```js
feed.get({
  enrich: true,
  with_own_reactions: true,
  reaction_kinds_filter: "like",
  user_id: "my_user",
});
```

If user liked the activity, activity will contain the details `own` field. Otherwise, it will be empty.